# Fastlane Integration with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, ruby, xcode, fastlane

I am trying to integrate for my sample project UberClone with Fastlane.
I have 3 Targets

> UberClone

> UberCloneTest

> UberCloneUITest

---

I created fastfile as below and downloaded fastlane but I need your help for integrate fastlane tests are okay or not. How can I build this file ?

```
  default_platform(:ios)


platform :ios do
# 1
  desc "ui test and unit tests need to check"
# 2
  lane :create_app do
# 3
​    produce
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run tests see https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/running-tests/

To run Swiftlint see https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/swiftlint/

I’d really recommend reading through the fastlane documentation. It can be hard to grasp at first but it gets easier to understand lanes and all the functionality. See https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/ and I also recommend checking out fastlane’s github samples.

For example to run swiftlint and then unit and UI tests run `fastlane tests`

```
default_platform(:ios)


platform :ios do

  lane :tests do
    swiftlint()
​    run_tests(scheme: "UberCloneTest")
​    run_tests(scheme: "UberCloneUITest")
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you for your reply and documentation but i have already read all docs but it needs little background. Also github examples are complicated not for beginner.

Comment: All i need to do is putting this fastfile into my file and run fastlane tests in command line ?

Comment: @DrainOpener - Yes you’ll want to update your fastfile and then with command line in your project directory you can run fastlane tests